# Which file (or code) actually control the monitor's brightness in "gnome-control-center"?

Tags: source-code

[At first, I tried to simulate <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F5 / F6</kbd> in order to control the monitor's brightness, but I totally failed.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23495426/is-fn-key-not-defined-in-x-window-in-x11-keysymdef-h)

So, I started to find out workarounds:

There is a built-in software called [`gnome-control-center`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+publishinghistory), so I tried to find out the solution from it.

[image]

We can see that there is a bar controlling monitor's brightness. Drag to the left for darkening, and vice versa.

I've downloaded the [source code for 12.04](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+source/gnome-control-center/1:3.4.2-0ubuntu0.13.2/+files/gnome-control-center_3.4.2.orig.tar.xz) [[site]](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+source/gnome-control-center/1:3.4.2-0ubuntu0.13.2), but I still couldn't find the code snippet which controls the monitor's brightness.

Could anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: you can try `xbacklight`, for example `xbacklight -set 80` but typically this means that you have some problem with your drivers. Which driver did you have installed ?

Comment: @user2485710 Where can I find the driver name installed by system autimatically?

Comment: @user2485710 Oh, my graphics driver is NVIDIA 331.20. BTW, the driver provided by NVIDIA works totally fine. I just want to control the brightness from software in the background.

Comment: I don't have any recent experience with the Nvidia drivers, anyhow the way you are supposed to follow to install proprietary drivers under Ubuntu is to use `Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers` which is basically the old `jockey-gtk` . Other methods are likely to be unsupported and you are supposed to know what you are doing as you do it. Wait for someone experienced with Nvidia software.